# Android and External Database

Tags: mysql, database, android-external-storage

I have to make an android application for data entry into database and show the data from the database, it will consist of a few textfileds,few spinners and button 'Enter' to which enters all data in database, selected text from spinners and inserted text in textfields will be entered in database. There should be 3 tables in database. So i ask for advice or recommendation how to start, which external database to use(can i build it with xampp?), what is the easiest way, i use android studio, and i'm new with android but i know little java...Thanks!

Comment: Is your mysql database being hosted somewhere? Because the way to go is to make a web service business layer that deals with the database and have the android app call the web service.

Comment: it should be offline, that's why i asked about xampp